# Android setOnTouchListener

Tags: android, gesture

I have read some different responses for this same question, so I dont know which one is right, then I decided to ask it again. Please try to not refer any other link in this answer. If you want to do so, I will be expecting a bit of extra explanation.

My question is:
I have an `ImageView` inside a `ViewPager`, my `ImageView` has some gestures detection(zoom and pan) and I am using the default `ViewPager`, which has swipe detection by default.
*How does the chain of onTouch events work? The lowest view in my hierarchy will always get onTouch and if the method returns false will parent handle it? Perhaps the opposite?*

I am asking that, because I have a `ImageView` which has gestures to left and right, and when I get in the edge of the image, I have to dispatch an event to the parent (a `ViewPager`) to handle the pagination event. any further tip in how to do it, it will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have managed that multiple touches in children views of ViewPager in a better way then onInterceptTouchEvent, I am saying that, because in my case, in order to know if I had to scroll the children views instead of the Pager, I needed the distance between the start and end points, and I didnt want to hold that variables and calculate the delta afterwards.

Anyways, After going into the source code for ViewPager, I found out that there is a really good method that I should be implementing for this reason. 
Here is my implementation:

```
@Override
protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
    if (v instanceof ImageViewTouch) {
        return ((ImageViewTouch) v).canScroll(dx);
    } else {
        return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
    }
}
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#ViewPager.canScroll%28android.view.View%2Cboolean%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29

Comment: Can you please post canScroll() method of a ImageViewTouch class? I am assuming you are using this ImageViewTouch (https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom)

Answer (score 1):

It works the opposite ViewPager eats touch events first, then ImageView will get it.

I would use onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) on a custom View Pager. On the MotionEvent you will want to analyze how many touch points are there by ev.getPointerCount().

If you have ev.getPointerCount() == 2, you will probably want to be doing pinch and zoom inside the ImageView.

If you have ev.getPointerCount() == 1, then you probably intent to swipe through pages of the View Pager or perform a pan in the ImageView. In order to distinguish between the two of these you will want to figure out if you are performing a Swipe Gesture with 1 finger or a simple MotionEvent.MOVE for a pan. The swipe gesture requires the user to surpass a predefined velocity. GestureDetector should take care of this for you.

Comment: hey, thanks for the tip, but actually thats what I was trying to do. and I didnt want to mess with Down pointer to hold the past value. as well as have an instance of my ImageView inside my ViewPager. So I have found another way to do it. will post my answer, so everybody can see it. thanks anyways